# Using the event-manager with multiple 'attachments'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to use the zend event-manager and have attachments from 2 classes. Then i try to trigger all events and go thru every attached function. Somehow i'm only able to receive one event and never get the other events. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
// create the event-manager
public static function getEventManager() {
    if(!self::$eventManager) {
        self::$eventManager = new \Zend_EventManager_EventManager();
    }
    return self::$eventManager;
}

// attach an event
Item\Plugin::getEventManager()->attach("item.getProvider", function($e) {
    $item = $e->getParam("item");
    return $this;
});

// attach another event in another class
Item\Plugin::getEventManager()->attach("item.getProvider", function($e) {
    $item = $e->getParam("item");
    return $this;
});

// get the events attached
$results = self::getEventManager()->trigger("item.getProvider", null, array("item" => $item), function($v) {
    return ($v instanceof Item);
});

if($results->stopped())
{
    $provider = array();

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $provider[] = $result;
    }
        return $provider;
    }
}
```

http://pastie.org/10522533#

Comment: Can you include that code in this post?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I included it now right in this post.